# is this function tail recursive?

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket, tail-recursion

in **racket**, i define the following function and am wondering whether it is *tail recursive*:

```
(define foo
  (λ (c m s1 s2)
      (if (< c m)
          (if (= (modulo m c) 0)
              (foo (+ c 1) m (+ s1 c) s2)
              (foo (+ c 2) m s1 (+ s2 c)))
          (cons s1 s2))))
```

my question is virtually like this, but i have to write something else to satisfy my *post quality standards*. actually, i do not know what is my *post quality standards*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is practically the same as your previous question. Yes, this is tail recursive: whenever a recursive call occurs in your function `foo`, it's in a tail position. Meaning: after the recursive call is performed, there's nothing else to do, that branch of execution ends. And the `(cons s1 s2)` part is the base case of the recursion, so it doesn't count. To see it more clearly, the `foo` procedure is equivalent to this:

```
(define (foo c m s1 s2)
  (cond ((>= c m)
         (cons s1 s2))                  ; base case of recursion
        ((= (modulo m c) 0)
         (foo (+ c 1) m (+ s1 c) s2))   ; recursive call is in tail position
        (else
         (foo (+ c 2) m s1 (+ s2 c))))) ; recursive call is in tail position
```

Let's see an example of when something is *not* a tail recursion. For instance, if the consequent part of the second `if` were defined like this:

```
(+ 1 (foo (+ c 1) m (+ s1 c) s2))
```

Then clearly the recursive call would not be in a tail position, because after the recursion returns an operation is performed: adding one to the result of the recursion.

Comment: it is hard for me to imagine how the interpreter repeatedly utilizes the same invoking stack as the optimization in this case.

Comment: It's clearer in my implementation above, think of the tail call of `foo` as a weird-looking `for` where the parameters are the variables that get updated in each iteration, and the first condition is the exit condition of the loop. Then it's easy to see that the same stack frame is reused between calls - only the parameter values need to be updated

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pseudocode (Common Lisp actually) translation of your code to frame-mutating version:

```
(defun foo (c m s1 s2)
  (prog 
      ((c c) (m m) (s1 s1) (s2 s2))  ; the frame
      BACK
      (if (< c m)
          (if (= (modulo m c) 0)
              (progn 
                (psetf s1 (+ s1 c)     ; set!
                       c  (+ c  1))    ;   in parallel
                (go BACK))
              (progn 
                (psetf s2 (+ s2 c)     ; set!
                       c  (+ c  2))    ;   in parallel
                (go BACK)))
          (return-from foo (cons s1 s2))))))
```

Since there's nothing more left to do after each tail call, we can just `(go BACK)`.

Answer (score 0):

The only calls to `foo` are in the tail position, so that function looks tail recursive to me.

Answer (score 0):

Section 11.20, page 59 of [Scheme R6RS](http://www.r6rs.org/final/r6rs.pdf) describes tail calls and shows the tail call position for the fundamental Scheme syntactic forms, like for `if` and `lambda`

Your calls to `foo` within `foo` are in tail position.  (Because they are in the inner `if` tail position, the outer `if` tail position and the `lambda` tail position.)